# how to antialiasing in the canvas and path

Tags: android, android-canvas

i meet a trouble  when i use  canvas.clipPath,it show sawtooth,it looks not smooth,i know if i used a Paint,i can use mPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) ,this can  antialiasing ,but in my code ,i cannot use paint.

```
public static void drawCurrentPageArea(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bitmap) {
    //cebakhja


    canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(getPath5(), Region.Op.XOR);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.restore();
}

public static Path getPath5()
{
    Path mPath5 = new Path();

    mPath5.moveTo(ptc.x, ptc.y);
    mPath5.quadTo(pte.x, pte.y, ptb.x,ptb.y);
    mPath5.lineTo(pta.x, pta.y);
    mPath5.lineTo(ptk.x, ptk.y);
    mPath5.quadTo(pth.x, pth.y, ptj.x,ptj.y);
    mPath5.lineTo(ptf.x, ptf.y);
    mPath5.close();
    return mPath5;
}
```

you can see i use canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null); paint is null.if i need add a paint ,can you have some advice? the pic is  as http://i.6.cn/cvbnm/36/5c/20/5d8d20e3bafe432d792793509f99131e.jpg

edit:i set the paint that is null ,but not effect

Comment: you say you can't use paint with ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG, why not?

Comment: you see in my code,i is not use paint,so i cannot use  ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG

Comment: I see that you don't, I ask why not.  ie, why not canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG));

Comment: i also use this method,but no effect.can you have other methods

Answer (score 9):

Try this.

```
private Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint() {
    {
        setAntiAlias(true);
        setFilterBitmap(true);
    }
};

public static void drawCurrentPageArea(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bitmap) {
    // cebakhja
    canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(getPath5(), Region.Op.XOR);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Comment: +1 - Better but not perfect. Is there another way to smooth the edges of a clipped image? If I just had to draw an oval shape I could use bitmap masking but that's not possible if I have to clip the round shape to a bitmap.

Comment: Just an idea: you can try to draw the path on top of the bitmap as a blurred transparent line some pixels wide with paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN)); (or was it DST_OUT?)

Comment: That's a pretty smart idea actually. I give it a try, thank you!

Comment: work's like a charm. At first I was afraid of OutOfMemoryErrors because I have to use two new Bitmaps but that doesn't seem to be a problem.